# Как изменить тему в других activity?

Tags: java, android

Я новичок и прошу помощи. Есть ThemesActivity в котором прописано динамическое изменение темы при выборе одного из radiobutton. Есть файл Utils.Java, который отвечает за смену темы и перезапуск activity. Как мне сделать так, чтобы при выборе (например dark radiobutton) у меня тема менялась не только в ThemesActivity, но и в остальных activity тоже? У меня есть еще MainActivity и InfoActivity.

Utils.Java

```
package com.example.calc;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;

public class Utils {
    private static int sTheme;
    public final static int THEME_DEFAULT = 0;
    public final static int THEME_DARK = 1;
    public final static int THEME_AMOLED = 2;
    /**
     * Set the theme of the Activity, and restart it by creating a new Activity of the same type.
     */
    public static void changeToTheme(Activity activity, int theme)
    {
        sTheme = theme;
        activity.finish();
        activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, activity.getClass()));
    }
    /** Set the theme of the activity, according to the configuration. */
    public static void onActivityCreateSetTheme(Activity activity)
    {
        switch (sTheme)
        {
            default:
            case THEME_DEFAULT:
                activity.setTheme(R.style.LightTheme);
                break;
            case THEME_DARK:
                activity.setTheme(R.style.DarkTheme);
                break;
            case THEME_AMOLED:
                activity.setTheme(R.style.AMOLEDTheme);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

ThemesActivity.Java

```
package com.example.calc;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ThemesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    RadioGroup radioGroup;
    static final private int CHOOSE_THIEF = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Utils.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_themes);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(0xFF616770);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Темы");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        radioGroup.clearCheck();

        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                switch (checkedId) {
                    case -1:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ничего не выбрано",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case R.id.light:
                        Utils.changeToTheme(ThemesActivity.this, Utils.THEME_DEFAULT);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Light тема",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case R.id.amoled:
                        Utils.changeToTheme(ThemesActivity.this, Utils.THEME_AMOLED);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "AMOLED тема",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case R.id.dark:
                        Utils.changeToTheme(ThemesActivity.this, Utils.THEME_DARK);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Dark тема",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case R.id.user1:
                        Toast t = Toast.makeText(ThemesActivity.this, "HumanZ тема", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
                        t.show();
                        Toast t1 = Toast.makeText(ThemesActivity.this, "Не работает", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        t1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,150);
                        t1.show();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, CHOOSE_THIEF);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_in,R.anim.alpha16);
                this.finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Одна активность не имеет доступа к `view` другой. Вам нужно для каждой активности прописать выбор темы в `onResume()`

Comment: Прописывать нужно в Utils.Java?

Comment: в методе `onResume()` каждой активности.

Comment: Я поздно отвечу, но нужно ли использовать вместе с методом onResume() метод onPause()?

Comment: нет, не нужно..